# Do websites grant their own JWT token after successful OpenID/OAuth2 login?

Tags: api, oauth2, openid

I am looking at implementing an Authorization Code with PKCE grant on a mobile app to communicate to an API.  What I am curious about is what applications currently do with the OpenID token that is granted to the user via Google.  Do servers typically use the token granted by Google to handle which user is interacting with the API or do servers take the information from the user info endpoint and grant their own token with claims that they control?

Answer (score 1):

Recommendation would be to generate ones own as then you are now in full control of that token, when it expires, etc. that said, I'm sure there is a site somewhere that doesn't follow this practice.

That said, you may keep a record of the original token as well for audit trail purposes.